# reading objects from R workspace

Tags: r

I loaded some objects into R workspace (of rstudio) and tried assigning to a variable (like this: x <- list("regular expression pattern forobjectName") so that the contents will be available for further analysis using merge function. R simply assigned the correct object name surrounded by quotes and merge() threw error when I passed x to it. Does anyone know which functions might be useful for reading the object which can then be assigned to a variable for further analysis?

Thanks

Comment: dump/source sound like they could be what you're looking for...

Comment: get and mget perhaps?

Comment: `ls()` returns a character vector... Not the objects and not even the object names. Think of objects in R as being of two general categories: data objects and language objects. The names of data objects are actually in the language object domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` function retrieves an object by name. Thus, if `x` is 1, you can use `get("x")` to get 1 :

```
> # Typing this on the R command line...
> x <- 1
> get("x")
[1] 1
```

You could use `get()` as part of an `lapply()` on a list of variable names to retrieve all objects that match the pattern you are looking for. Here's example in which I `merge()` two data frames retrieved indirectly.

The `x <- lapply(ls(pat="^df"), get)` is the core statement relevant to you.

```
> # First we define the data frames
> df1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5)
> df2 <- data.frame(a=3:7, b=3:7)
> ls(pat="^df")
[1] "df1" "df2"
> # This just gets their names
> x <- ls(pat="^df")
> x
[1] "df1" "df2"
> # This retrieves the actual objects
> x <- lapply(ls(pat="^df"), get)
> x
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

[[2]]
  a b
1 3 3
2 4 4
3 5 5
4 6 6
5 7 7

> merge(x[[1]], x[[2]])
  a b
1 3 3
2 4 4
3 5 5
```

Comment: Also, as I mentioned above, `mget` is specifically intended for retrieving multiple objects. No need for `lapply`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about mget() till now.

Comment: Excellent! Both x <- lapply(ls(pat="^df"), get) and mget approaches worked. Thanks everyone for your useful comments and help in providing the right answers.